# Python: Search Facebook API with multiple criteria

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Python to call the Facebook API. This is a two part question.

Let's start with:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI('token')
criteria = {"whatever I'm passing"}
print graph.request('/search', criteria)
```

**----Part 1----**

I can't quite figure out how to pass the location search arguments to `graph.request()`

The API v2.2 docs describe location as:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
    /search?
    type=location&
    center=37.76,-122.427&
    distance=1000
```

But if I try

```
criteria = {'q': {'center': '37.76,-122.427'}, 'type': 'location'}
```

I get `facebook.GraphAPIError: (#12) location search is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher`, which doesn't make any sense to me.

If I try:

```
criteria = {'q': {'center': '37.76,-122.427'}, 'type': 'place'}
```

It returns an empty list.

**----Part 2----**

How do I search multiple things at once? For example, a person search would look like:

```
criteria = {'q': 'john smith', 'type': 'user'}
```

And that works fine, but now my `'q'` argument is occupied by the name and `'type'` is occupied by the search type. How can I combine Part 1 and Part 2 to perform a search of a user AND his/her location?

Comment: If the documentation say it should work and it doesn't file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @WizKid I am a noob, so I always assume I'm doing something wrong. Me claiming it's an api bug would be like someone else claiming their problem is in the compiler.

Comment: If the API v2.2 docs say to do in a certain way and you get an error back saying location search is deprecated that really sounds like a documentation bug

Comment: I'm wondering now if I'm seeing this error because I did not pass an argument for `distance`. However, this leads me back to my question about how the heck do I translate the example code into python so that I can pass multiple criteria to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there is indeed a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298472860351424/